# から～から for a range of activities

Tags: grammar, particles, parsing, particle-から

I came across a use of から that seems unusual to me:

> 伊月は　旅行の手配から運転から　何もかもしてくれて　本当に　頼りになる
>
> > From the trip preparations, from the driving, Itsuki is taking care of anything and everything; she truly is reliable.
> >
> > > From the trip preparations to the driving, Itsuki is taking care of everything. She is truly reliable.

I'm curious about the way から is used here. It seems like a variation of a structure used to describe a range of activities, like から～まで、から～にかけて、から～にいたるまで.

Except in this example, there are two start points, and the end point is included in 何もかも ("anything and everything") instead of being indicated with something like まで.

I haven't been able to find an example like is in the usual grammars. What exactly is this use of から? Is this a casual modification of the other forms, or is there something particular about this sentence (何もかも、してくれる、etc.) that results in this configuration?

Comment: It's difficult to explain but it's a way of saying it.

Comment: sounds unusual to me too, but I guess it could be correct, because I don't know which is the start and which is the end, therefore, instead of から～まで, it becomes から～から. (I have no citation, as this is just my comprehension)

Comment: It makes me think of the English structure, "From Vienna to Paris to Berlin, the great cities of Europe were engulfed in revolution in the spring of 1848." The "from~to~to" never made much sense to me in terms of literal meaning of the words, since it's a range with multiple endpoints, but it's still obvious what the sentence as a whole conveys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"から" means "from" I would say.

I believe it is useful to first look to the expression "何から何まで" and take from there. It means "everything" covering from A to Z you can think of. 
For example:

- 何から何まで母親が面倒みている。His mother looks after everything for him.

"旅行の手配から運転から" are some examples included in "everything" and it basically leads to "何から何まで". Perhaps the complete sentence could be:

> 伊月は旅行の手配から運転から何から何まで、何もかもしてくれて本当に頼りになる。

"何もかも" means "anything and everything" and having it in the sentence could be regarded as an emphasis by repeating the word with the same meaning. So it can be omitted as below.

> 伊月は旅行の手配から運転から何から何までしてくれて本当に頼りになる。

Suppose you went a lengthy and challenging oversea adventure which you had never done. You got to know someone experienced and he/she arranged everything. Booking flights, transportations/logistics/accommodations at the destination, translations, looked after you when you got sick, guided you through the journey, etc etc. Then you would say.

> ガイドは飛行機の手配から、宿から、通訳から、なにもかもしてくれて本当に助かった。

Answer (score 0):

What's the source? I think it's just a typo and that it should be 運転まで as you noted... Had it been in the reverse order, 運転から、旅行の手配から it could have been a way to emphasize the extent of Itsuki's work, though.

Comment: It's a line from a comic. So it's possible the author and publisher let a typo go through, but I'm more inclined to believe that it's an intentional use, merely one that is informal.

Comment: It does not look typo. "家事から、洗濯から、掃除から、本当に何か何まで至れり尽くせりのサービスで大満足。" etc.